# How can I extract all contiguous values of a multidimensional array stored in HDF5 between two indices?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indices

I have a 2D array stored as a dataset in an HDF5 file. Let's assume it has dimension (100, 100). Given two indices, say x1,y1 = (10,50) and x2,y2 = (30,20), I would like to grab all elements "between" (10,50) and (30,20) and read them into a new 1D array. One approach would be to read into memory the full dataset, flatten it, and then use numpy's ravel_multi_index to extract the corresponding "flat" indices like so:

```
import numpy as np
dataset = np.random.rand(100,100)
flat_index_1 = np.ravel_multi_index((10,50), (100,100))
flat_index_2 = np.ravel_multi_index((30,20), (100,100))
data_sliced = dataset.flatten()[flat_index_1:flat_index_2]
```

However, this method is not great if the dimension of the 2D array, here (100,100), becomes larger than can be efficiently stored in memory. If the dataset were (1e6, 1e6) this would require loading a massive dataset - depending on x1,y1 and x2,y2 you may only need a handful of contiguous elements in the end making this approach far from ideal. Because you cannot flatten an HDF5 dataset (without altering the file or reading arrays into memory), I am wondering what the best approach would be. Is there a way to use np.nditer to get a list of iterables between two indices?

Comment: Forget `nditer`.  It doesn't work on a `h5py` dataset.  And even on a numpy array i don't see how it would help.

Comment: I find that nditer does work on h5py datasets. I can do a trivial example where I load a dataset (not in memory as an array), and for each item in `np.nditer(dataset)` increment a counter. I get the expected result.

Comment: But timings for `np.nditer(dataset[:])` are the same, indicating that `nditer` is first loading the whole dataset as an array, and then iterating.  It's not iterating directly on the dataset (which would be very slow).  Nor doesn't it enhance the fancy indexing capabilities of `h5py`.

Comment: Interesting - fortunately it is fast enough for my needs at the moment (interactive plotting of large datasets), and in fact, this solves my issue since I can simply construct the iterator over `dataset[:].ravel()[min:max]` without losing much time. I'll have to look into alternatives if this becomes too slow. Any idea what is actually going on internally when nditer constructs the iterator? It seems like it's not actually reading the dataset into memory since it is much faster as you say. And obviously the memory usage of the iterator itself is quite small. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is the dataset even c-contiguous or chunked? (very likely chunked on a (1e6,1e6) dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly more compact:

```
data_sliced = dataset.flat[flat_index_1:flat_index_2]
```

though surprisingly this use of `ravel` is faster:

```
data_sliced = dataset.ravel()[flat_index_1:flat_index_2]
```

That said, I don't think this applies to a `h5py` dataset.

With an array, your flat indexing can be turned back into an advanced indexing tuple:

```
In [21]: flat_index_1                                                                                  
Out[21]: 1050
In [22]: flat_index_2                                                                                  
Out[22]: 3020
In [23]: idx = np.unravel_index(np.arange(flat_index_1, flat_index_2), (100,100))   
In [26]: idx                                                                                           
Out[26]: (array([10, 10, 10, ..., 30, 30, 30]), array([50, 51, 52, ..., 17, 18, 19]))
In [27]: idx[0].shape                                                                                  
Out[27]: (1970,)
In [28]: data_sliced2 = dataset[idx]                                                                   
In [29]: np.allclose(data_sliced, data_sliced2)                                                        
Out[29]: True
```

I'm not sure if this works in `h5py`.  It may violate the increasing order requirement.  Plus `h5py` warns that this advanced indexing can be slow.

Another option is to load simple slice of the dataset, and take the raveled selection from that.  That could be faster, even though it requires some index fiddling.

For example load just the rows that we need:

```
In [30]: subset = dataset[10:31, :]                                                                    
In [31]: subset.shape                                                                                  
Out[31]: (21, 100)
In [32]: subset[idx[0]-10, idx[1]].shape                                                               
Out[32]: (1970,)
In [33]: np.allclose(subset[idx[0]-10, idx[1]], data_sliced)                                           
Out[33]: True
```

or

```
In [34]: idx1 = np.ravel_multi_index((0,50), subset.shape)                                             
In [35]: idx2 = np.ravel_multi_index((20,20), subset.shape)                                            
In [36]: idx1, idx2                                                                                    
Out[36]: (50, 2020)
In [37]: np.allclose(subset.ravel()[idx1:idx2], data_sliced)                                           
Out[37]: True
```

Selecting columns as well probably isn't useful: `dataset[10:31, 20:51]`